# How to embed a flash file in a Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, flash, embedded-flashplayer

I am trying to embed a flash file onto the homepage of my Ruby application. The homepage is in /app/view/home, and the flash file is in the projects /public/flash/myflash.swf.

When I load the home page, I don't see anything, although the text is bumped below a square of the proper size I defined the file as.

The code I am using to try and load the file is

```
<div id="flashContent">
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="346" height="383" id="Blox" align="middle">
            <param name="movie" value="/flash/Blox.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="play" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="false" />
            <param name="wmode" value="window" />
            <param name="scale" value="showall" />
            <param name="menu" value="true" />
            <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
            <param name="salign" value="" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    </object>
</div>
```

I am thinking that either I am calling the file wrong by using `value=/flash/Blox.swf`, or that I am storing my flash file in the wrong place period.

How can I get my flash file to load? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm curious about this too...

Comment: From the name you mentioned in your description, the url value should be "/flash/myflash.swf".  Also, consider using SWFObject: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ to avoid browser compatibility issues.

Comment: Oh, and check whether the SWF is actually not found (404), or there are errors within the ActionScript program: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/logging_04.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by including and `<embed src>` tag in the object. Not the best solution, but it worked for what I needed.